# Java / Android: simulate click on submit button (HTML)

Tags: java, android, html, click, simulate

I want to **simulate** a **click** **on** a website on a **submit-type** **button**

this is the code for now, but apparently it does not work:

```
                                 String id = "x";
                                 String pw = "y";

                                 web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

                                 web.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                                         "document.getElementsByName('authid')[0].value = '"+id +"';" +
                                         "document.getElementsByName('authpw')[0].value = '"+pw +"';" +
                                         "var submit = document.getElementsByClassName('inputbutton');" +
                                         "submit[0].submit(); };");
```

**and this is how it looks like: [Screenshot of Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42vQ.png)**

the code for the button on the website:

```
<input type="submit" value="OK" class="inputbutton">
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the vote up, I've got the answer:

instead of `submit[0].submit();` in the last line of the first code part it has to be `submit[0].click();`